# Tools to inspect folders of CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css

Are there any tools out there than can inspect sets of JS or CSS files and report function or class name clashes?
I have a large project and there are many JS and CSS files. Naming conventions have until now not been enforced and I would like to scan all the files for violations between files. Ideally detect duplicate CSS class names as well as duplicate JS names.

Comment: Firebug, google chrome?

Comment: That won't find clashes in names, simply just report the most recent. I would like to sanity an entire projects CSS and JS to make sure that regardless of what's loaded for a specific page, I don't have name clashes that might result in confusion for the programmer, or worse, an error on page.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692072/code-analysis-for-css-html-and-javascript

Comment: Also, look into google's closure compiler

Comment: No automated tools that I'm aware of.  I'd imagine you could probably whip up a script that would do this for you.  Just parse each file and maintain a hash of function names/classnames and their "collisions".  Of course, the complexity of this really depends on how uniformly people have been writing their css/js class/function definitions.

Comment: @joeltime - Yeah, that looks like what I'm going to be doing. CSS should be ok but JS will be more complicated. I'd been looking for something to GIT though, so maybe this will be a fun little side project :-)

Comment: There's [`antlr`](http://www.antlr3.org/), which has also links to [javascript](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) grammars. If you do it yourself, this might help.

Answer (score 2):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) can do this, and is especially good and finding duplicate Javascript declarations (commercial, free trial). (If you download this and run the code duplication analysis, just turn on the checkboxes for CSS and Javascript).

For just CSS, you can use [mincss](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/mincss). This will also remove CSS classes that are never referenced in HTML; you'll need to tell it about any classes that reference elements that are only dynamically generated.